# Is there any real time paypal ipn service

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, asp.net-web-api

PayPal has explicitly stated that their IPN service should not be relied on during the user checkout process. I believe the idea here is that IPN should be a tracking mechanism to keep our back end data in sync with PayPal's data. What I want to do is to use express checkout but enforce an "IPN" to hit my server, and for my server to appropriately respond, before anything is finalized.

I can then ensure that I only give out content to users once they've paid, and that if a user does pay for a piece of content they do not have to refresh or wait for the IPN to come in. One of the problems with doing this using a return url and query string, is that i have a single page website on the firefox phone. The phone gets data from our API web service. So i need this endpoint to be hit regardless of the return url.

I know there are some more features with PayPal advanced developer, at a fee. I'm fine with that if that's the case, but i just want to know my options first.

Comment: IPN is inherently asynchronous. You could put a loop in your web service that checks whether the IPN callback has occurred and the user's account has updated.

Comment: Nothing in PayPal's "advanced" or "pro" products will add significant new options beyond either a) taking action upon the API response or b) taking action upon the IPN (delayed; usually a few seconds but potentially longer). The RESTful solution provides "webhooks" but these are basically more modern IPNs :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name implies, IPN is instant.  There are rare occasions where it may be slightly delayed, but that doesn't happen often, especially on the live servers.

You can build your IPN listener to do whatever you need as far as updating a database, generating custom email notifications, hitting 3rd party web services, etc. and those actions will be triggered in real-time.

You just need to get your listener created and configured in the PayPal IPN settings, or you can also pass the IPN URL in the NotifyURL parameter of your Express Checkout API calls.

If you happen to be using WordPress you may be interested in my [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) plugin.  It gets you up-and-running with IPN very quickly, and then you can hook into the plugin to trigger your own functions based on different IPN types or payment statuses.

**Extra Info from Comments**

As mentioned, IPN is a post-transaction thing.  What you could do, though, is setup Auth and Capture on your checkout system.  When the order comes through you would run it as an Authorization, and when you're ready to "finalize" you would run the capture.

You would get an IPN for both the authorization and the capture.  So, one thing you could do, if it suits you, would be to run the order as an Authorization, and then within your IPN script, go ahead and run the capture.  That way you could do whatever checks you want to do and only capture if they pass.

In passing cases, the capture would take place "almost" instantly when the order takes place.  Cases where it doesn't pass, you could either void the Auth or let it sit there in a pending state.

Comment: It is certainly *not* 'instant'. In my experience it is, usually, what I would describe as 'quick': i.e. within minutes, not milliseconds.

Comment: Well that adds a level of confidence, i suppose, is there anyway that i can enforce that my server responds to the IPN before paypal finalizes the purchase?

Comment: @Ukemi PayPal has *already* finalized the purchased, and is notifying you about the payment.

Comment: @EJP yeah i was figuring as much. Im trying to implement paypal in a way that it will notify my api before finalizing. And also require my server to respond.

Comment: @Ukemi Well that's not how it works. Rethink your design. I don't do anything in my system about enabling the product for the user until the IPN is received. When the return_url is hit, I tell him to wait for a confirming email, which I send after processing the IPN.

Comment: Actually, IPN tells you about *transactions* that are complete at PayPal (not just "payments"). If you use authorizations, PayPal can send you an IPN telling you that the authorization is complete (meaning funds are guaranteed available), and you could then take action on your side and capture (or release, in exceptional cases) the authorization. Just an idea in case this helps the OP. But EJP's flow is an excellent one.